# CSS multicol right column bigger than left

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I've been playing around with multicolumns as I want to give my website a book-like feel to it. I want the paragraph elements to stay intact so I added the break-inside: avoid property. Unfortunately, certain sized paragraphs causes the break to move the paragraph to the right column, which looks pretty bad since now the right column is bigger than the left one. One would assume that in balancing columns, it would always make the left column larger?

I feel a way around this would be to manually pick the paragraph where the break occurs by adding a class to it but I was wondering if there's a more universal fix to this.

Here's an example of what I mean:
http://www.theworldwars.net/resources/resources.php?r=vdes_us

Here's an example of how it should look:
http://www.theworldwars.net/resources/resources.php?r=vdes_de

Thanks.

```
.multicol {
    columns: 512px 2;
    column-gap: 5%;
}

p {
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: maybe a picture of what you want to attain can help us understand whats your goal.

Comment: PLease read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Paragraphs are the very things that should be wrapping. And yes, this has always been a problem with multi cols. there are widows and orphans, but they don't seem to have browser support. You would be best off placing <hr> into your document where you want the break to be with the css hr {break-inside: avoid;}

Comment: I literally added two links that show exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @Carol, yes that is my backup plan if nothing else works, was hoping there was a more universal solution though

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work for firefox:

```
@media and (min-width: 1540px) {

    .multicol {
        columns: 2;
        column-gap: 5%;
    }
    
    p {
        break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you meant "screen" after the @media but in any case this doesn't work, the right column is still bigger than the left one.

Comment: Nope didn't work. You still have the right column bigger than the left